# Unity 3D C# - Setting Material's Emission Texture via Script

Tags: unity, c#

[image]

Hi, I just wanted to know if there is a way to set emission's texture via script. I haven't found nothing in the documentation, neither on any forum, except the setting of the emission color setting via script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the Standard shader, you will see the name of the property you want :

```
_EmissionColor("Color", Color) = (0,0,0)
_EmissionMap("Emission", 2D) = "white" {}
```

Then, using the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTexture.html) you will see how to assign a named texture to a given material.

```
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetTexture("_EmissionMap", yourTexture ) ;
```

Here is a [link to download the shaders provided by Unity](http://netstorage.unity3d.com/unity/38b4efef76f0/builtin_shaders-5.5.0f3.zip?_ga=1.156741819.1872458862.1483561510).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also explored the other Standard Shader Properties you mentioned.